# Not able to hide the search when the user clicks outside of search bar in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in my Ionic App and I have added a search bar in my Ionic app but the problem is that when I click outside of search result, the search bar should hide but it is not hiding and the result is also there.

I want when the user clicks outside of the search bar, it should hide the search bar and it should also clear the results.

This is my **app.html**:

```
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle start>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <div class="mydiv2">
      <ion-icon name="search" class="myicon22" (click)="hasSearchnot()"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-searchbar *ngIf="HasSearch" (input)="setSearchProducts($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list *ngIf="HasSearch">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of finalproductsearch" (click)="showProductDetails(item)">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{'images.pro_images}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      {{ item.product_name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

In this view, I have a search icon and when the user clicks on the search icon the search bar will open.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
HasSearch: boolean;
hasSearchnot()
{
    this.HasSearch = !this.HasSearch;
}

getsearchproducts()
{
    this.restProvider.getproductsforsearch()
      .then(data => {
      this.searchproduct = data;
      this.finalseaproduct = this.searchproduct.msg;
      });
}
```

My search results are showing fine but the problem is that when I click outside of the search results, it should close the search bar and clear the search results but this is not happening.

When I move to the next page, the previous search results are still there. I want to clear the search results when the user moves to the next page.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure but I would suggest that if you clear your "finalproductsearch" variable in "hasSearchnot" method then it will behave as you want.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd. Okay and how to hide the search bar when the user click somewhere outside of the searchbar. like the popover.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd. Can you please help me with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works properly as per your requirement, Try this:

**app.html:**

```
<ion-navbar (click)="hideSearchbar($event)" >
  <button ion-button menuToggle start>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="mydiv2">
    <ion-icon name="search" class="myicon22" (click)="hasSearchnot($event)"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="HasSearch" (input)="setSearchProducts($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-content  (click)="hideSearchbar($event)">
<ion-list *ngIf="HasSearch">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of finalproductsearch" (click)="showProductDetails(item)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src="{{'images.pro_images}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    {{ item.product_name }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
HasSearch: boolean;
  hasSearchnot(e) {
    console.log("hasearch searchbar", this.HasSearch);

    if(e.target.classList.contains('myicon22')){
          this.finalsearchproduct = " ";    
      this.HasSearch = !this.HasSearch;

    }
  }
  hideSearchbar(e) {
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('myicon22')){

    if (this.HasSearch == true) {
      this.HasSearch = false;
      this.finalsearchproduct = " ";
    }
  }
  }
  getSearchProducts() {
    this.restProvider.getproductsforsearch()
      .then(data => {
      this.searchproduct = data;
      this.finalseaproduct = this.searchproduct.msg;
      });
  }
```

Here I've used **e.target.classList.contains('myicon22')** this will return true or false as per that particular tag has "myicon22" as a child class or not and by using that logic we can hide search bar when the user click somewhere outside of the searchbar.

Thanks.